# Garbage collection tuning in Spark: how to estimate size of Eden?

Tags: apache-spark, garbage-collection, jvm

I am reading about garbage collection tuning in *Spark: The Definitive Guide* by Bill Chambers and Matei Zaharia. This chapter is largely based on [Spark's documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning). Nevertheless, the authors extend the documentation with an example of how to deal with too many minor collections but not many major collections.

Both official documentation and the book state that:

> If there are too many minor collections but not many major GCs,
>   allocating more memory for Eden would help. You can set the size of
>   the Eden to be an over-estimate of how much memory each task will
>   need. If the size of Eden is determined to be E, then you can set the
>   size of the Young generation using the option -Xmn=4/3*E. (The scaling
>   up by 4/3 is to account for space used by survivor regions as well.) (See [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning))

The book offers an example (*Spark: The Definitive Guide*, first ed., p. 324):

> If your task is reading data from HDFS, the amount of memory used by
>   the task can be estimated by using the size of the data block read
>   from HDFS. Note that the size of a decompressed block is often two or
>   three times the size of the block. So if you want to have three or
>   four tasks' worth of working space, and the HDFS block size is 128 MB,
>   we can estimate size of Eden to be 43,128 MB.

Assuming that each uncompressed block takes even `512 MB` and we have `4` tasks, and we scale up by `4/3`, I don't really see how you can come up with the estimate of `43,128 MB` of memory for Eden.

I would rather answer that `~3 GB` should be enough for Eden given the book's assumptions.

Could anyone explain how this estimation should be calculated?

Comment: Are you actually facing the problem? If so, just post GC logs instead of citing a book.

Comment: Nope. Just wondering whether the presented estimation is accurate. Intuitively, it is much overestimated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think [the new Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/tuning.html) make it clear:

> As an example, if your task is reading data from HDFS, the amount of
>   memory used by the task can be estimated using the size of the data
>   block read from HDFS. Note that the size of a decompressed block is
>   often 2 or 3 times the size of the block. So if we wish to have 3 or 4
>   tasks’ worth of working space, and the HDFS block size is 128 MB, we
>   can estimate size of Eden to be 4*3*128MB.

So, it's `4*3*128 MB` rather than what the book says (i.e. `43,128 MB`).